# LEGO EV3 Ultrasonic sensor missing from Home Edition programmer

Tags: ev3, programming, sensor-ultrasonic

I'll get straight to the point: When I open my LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Home Edition programmer and try to use an ultrasonic sensor, there is no option for it in any blocks. I don't even see any allusion to the ultrasonic sensor existing at all. Is there any way at all to use the US sensor AND the IR sensor at once? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EV3 Home edition software does not come with blocks for ultrasonic sensor, unlike Education edition. However you can still add them as explained in [this guide](http://robotsquare.com/2014/06/25/tutorial-gyro-ultrasonic-sensor-ev3-home-edition/).